# Singular and Sheaf Cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex manifold of dimension $n$. Thus, it's a real manifold of dimension $2n$.

Now cohomology is a topological concept so it should not depend upon the structure given on a topological space.

We know that $k^{th}$ Singular cohomology of $X$ is $0$ for $k \gt 2n$. We can also define a sheaf cohomology on that space using derived functor approach of Grothendieck. Then (by a result of Grothendieck) we know that k'th sheaf cohomology is $0$ for $k \gt n$.

Now, for constant sheaves [say **R**], the sheaf cohomology agrees with singular cohomology [with coefficient **R**]. Does this means that even the $k^{th}$ singular cohomology of $X$ vanishes for $k \gt n$?

[Edited] I now feel that the result which says that sheaf and singular agrees is actually this that $k^{th}$ sheaf cohomology [of a complex manifold and constant sheaf] will agree with $2k^{th}$ singular cohomology [of the underlying real manifold]. Is this correct?? I would still like others to comment.

Thanks.

Comment: @user1767: I assume you're referring to the theorem of Grothendieck in Hartshorne III.2? That's true for the *combinatorial* dimension of a noetherian space, which is not the same as the dimension of a manifold (indeed, a manifold is not a noetherian space).

Comment: @Akhil, Thanks, that helped. I guess there is no corresponding vanishing theorem for sheaf cohomology on a manifold.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The cohomological dimension of a *real* $n$-manifold $M$ is $n$: this means that $H^i(M,\mathscr F)=0$ for each sheaf $\mathscr F$ of abelian groups on $M$ if $i>n$, and that there exist sheaves $\mathcal F$ on $M$ with $H^n(M,\mathscr F)\neq0$. You'll find this proved in Bredon's book on *Sheaf theory*, §II.16.

It follows that the cohomological dimension of a *complex* $n$-manifold is $2n$. For example, you reach the maximum, at least for compact ones, for the constant sheaf $\mathbb R$.

The answer to your «Does this means that even the k'th singular cohomology of X vanishes for k > n??» question is *No* (You can answer it without determining the cohomological dimension: just consider a compact complex $n$-manifold, which is automatically oriented: what is it $2n$-th cohomology group?)

The question in you [Edited] paragraph also has a negative answer. Consider examples to see that it is so.

Comment: Thank you, this clears the picture. Unfortunately, i cant upvote you now [not sufficient reputations].

Answer (score 8):

The statement is the following: If you take a variety with the *analytic* topology (or a complex manifold), then yes, sheaf cohomology of the constant sheaf agrees with singular cohomology. More generally, sheaf cohomology of a constant sheaf on a *locally contractible space* agrees with singular cohomology of that space. I think there's an explanation of this somewhere in Warner's book "Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups".

On the other hand, if you have an irreducible variety with the *Zariski* topology, then sheaf cohomology $H^i$ of the constant sheaf is zero for $i > 0$, because the constant sheaf is flasque.

Further remarks: If what you want is to be able to deal with singular cohomology in a more "algebraic" way, you can do so by using the Hodge decomposition $H^n(X;\mathbb{C}) = \bigoplus_{p+q=n}H^q(X,\Omega^p)$ which expresses singular cohomology in terms of sheaf cohomologies of $\Omega^p$'s. This works if your $X$ is a compact Kähler manifold, e.g., a smooth projective variety. If your $X$ is an algebraic variety, you can also use etale cohomology for an "algebraic" way of dealing with singular cohomology; see Milne's book/notes on etale cohomology for more.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Hodge decomposition gives rise to another question. We are using complex coefficients for singular cohomology [on the left side of the expression] because X is a complex manifold. Right? Does similar decomposition exists for say real manifold [where we can use **R** coefficients for singular cohomology] ??

Comment: I don't know if this will be helpful but -- another way to express Hodge decomposition for compact Kaehler manifolds is "Every cohomology class (coeffs in $\mathbb{C}$) has a unique $\overline{\partial}$-harmonic representative". There is an analogous statement for compact Riemannian manifolds, namely: "Every cohomology class (coeffs in $\mathbb{R}$) has a unique $d$-harmonic representative", where $d$ is the usual de Rham derivative.

Comment: Doesn't one need to add paracompactness for the claim in your first paragraph? (The long line is a counterexample otherwise, iirc)